# Finding an isomomorph to a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

I need to find an isomorph between the spaces $\Bbb{R}^3$ and vector space with defined operations on $\Bbb{R}^3$:

$$\vec{v} \oplus \vec{w} = \vec v + \vec w - \vec u$$ 
$$r \odot \vec{v} = r \cdot (\vec v - \vec u) + \vec u $$
Where $\vec u$ is fixed to be 
      $$\vec u =  \begin{pmatrix}
   2 \\ 0 \\ -1
    \end{pmatrix}$$

I'm lost at any way to do this, I tried
 $$f:   \begin{pmatrix}
   x \\ y \\ z
    \end{pmatrix}
\rightarrow
  \begin{pmatrix}
   x-2 \\ y \\ z+1
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
But scalar multiplication didn't hold, how do I go about finding an isomorph, is there a systematic way? Or do I just keep guessing?